# Custom validation rules required when select box

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I have a scope that can select company, store, department, when selecting company, the company field will appear for users to enter. similarly when selecting the store, the company and store fields will appear for users to enter. and when selecting the department, all 3 fields appear. My problem is that I have to set the rule so that when selecting company, only company will be requried, when the store is selected, the company and store fields are requried. Here are the rules, but all 3 fields are required. Click on scope and show the corresponding fields, I write in the script

[image]
This is the rules function:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'assigned_company' => 'required',
            'assigned_store' =>'required',
            'assigned_department' =>'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'assigned_company.required' => 'The company field is required.',
            'assigned_store.required' => 'The store field is required.',
            'assigned_department.required' => 'The department field is required.'
        ];
    }
```

And script:

```
$('input[name=checkout_to_type_contract]').on("change",function () {
        var object_type = $('input[name=checkout_to_type_contract]:checked').val();
        var object_id = $('#assigned_company option:selected').val();
        if (object_type == 'company') {
            $('#current_assets_box').fadeOut();
            $('#assigned_company').show();
            $('#assigned_store').hide();
            $('#assigned_department').hide();
            $('.notification-callout').fadeOut();
        } else if (object_type == 'store') {
            $('#current_assets_box').fadeOut();
            $('#assigned_company').show();
            $('#assigned_store').show();
            $('#assigned_department').hide();
            $('.notification-callout').fadeOut();
        } else  {
            $('#assigned_company').show();
            $('#assigned_store').show();
            $('#assigned_department').show();
            if (object_id) {
                $('#current_assets_box').fadeIn();
            }
            $('.notification-callout').fadeIn();
        }
    });
```

This is html. because it is too long so i will take the related parts

```
<!--Scope-->
<div class="form-group" id="assignto_selector"{!!  (isset($style)) ? ' style="'.e($style).'"' : ''  !!}>
    {{ Form::label('name', trans('general.scope'), array('class' => 'col-md-3 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            @if ((isset($scope_company_contract)) && ($scope_company_contract!='false'))
            <label class="btn btn-default active">
                <input name="checkout_to_type_contract" value="company" type="radio" checked="checked"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{ trans('general.company') }}
            </label>
            @endif
            @if ((isset($scope_store_contract)) && ($scope_store_contract!='false'))
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input name="checkout_to_type_contract" value="store" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> {{ trans('general.store') }}
            </label>
            @endif
            @if ((isset($scope_department_contract)) && ($scope_department_contract!='false'))
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input name="checkout_to_type_contract" value="department" class="active" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> {{ trans('general.department') }}
            </label>
            @endif

            {!! $errors->first('checkout_to_type_contract', '<span class="alert-msg"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> :message</span>') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Company -->
<div id="assigned_company" class="form-group{{ $errors->has($fieldname) ? ' has-error' : '' }}"{!!  (isset($style)) ? ' style="'.e($style).'"' : ''  !!}>
    {{ Form::label($fieldname, $translated_name, array('class' => 'col-md-3 control-label')) }}
    <div class="col-md-7{{  ((isset($required) && ($required =='true'))) ?  ' required' : '' }}">
        <select class="js-data-ajax" data-endpoint="companies" data-placeholder="{{ trans('general.select_company') }}" name="{{ $fieldname }}" style="width: 100%" id="company_select">
            @if ($company_id = Input::old($fieldname, (isset($item)) ? $item->{$fieldname} : ''))
                <option value="{{ $company_id }}" selected="selected">
                    {{ (\App\Models\Company::find($company_id)) ? \App\Models\Company::find($company_id)->name : '' }}
                </option>
            @else
                <option value="">{{ trans('general.select_company') }}</option>
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>


    {!! $errors->first($fieldname, '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3"><span class="alert-msg"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> :message</span></div>') !!}

</div>

<!-- Store -->
<div id="assigned_store" class="form-group{{ $errors->has($fieldname) ? ' has-error' : '' }}"{!!  (isset($style)) ? ' style="'.e($style).'"' : ''  !!}>
        {{ Form::label($fieldname, $translated_name, array('class' => 'col-md-3 control-label')) }}
        <div class="col-md-7{{  ((isset($required) && ($required =='true'))) ?  ' required' : '' }}">
            <select class="store_select" data-endpoint="" data-placeholder="Select Store" name="{{ $fieldname }}" style="width: 100%" id="store_select">
                @if ($storeSelect = Input::old($fieldname, (isset($item)) ? $item->{$fieldname} : ''))
                    <option value="{{ $storeSelect }}" selected="selected">
                        {{ (\App\Models\Store::find($storeSelect)) ? \App\Models\Store::find($storeSelect)->name : '' }}
                    </option>
                @else
                    <option value="">{{ trans('admin.store.table.select_store') }}</option>
                @endif
            </select>
        </div>


        {!! $errors->first($fieldname, '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3"><span class="alert-msg"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> :message</span></div>') !!}

    </div>
<!-- Department -->
<div id="assigned_department" class="form-group{{ $errors->has($fieldname) ? ' has-error' : '' }}"{!!  (isset($style)) ? ' style="'.e($style).'"' : ''  !!}>

    {{ Form::label($fieldname, $translated_name, array('class' => 'col-md-3 control-label')) }}

    <div class="col-md-7{{  ((isset($required) && ($required =='true'))) ?  ' required' : '' }}">
        <select class="department_select" data-endpoint="departments" data-placeholder="{{ trans('general.select_department') }}" name="{{ $fieldname }}" style="width: 100%" id="department_select">
            @if ($department_id = Input::old($fieldname, (isset($item)) ? $item->{$fieldname} : ''))
                <option value="{{ $department_id }}" selected="selected">
                    {{ (\App\Models\Department::find($department_id)) ? \App\Models\Department::find($department_id)->name : '' }}
                </option>
            @else
                <option value="">{{ trans('general.select_department') }}</option>
            @endif
        </select>
    </div>


    {!! $errors->first($fieldname, '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3"><span class="alert-msg"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> :message</span></div>') !!}

</div>
```

Comment: Can we also see your html form

Comment: Yes, I edited it

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rules to validate against your checkout type.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'checkout_to_type_contract' => 'required',
        'assigned_company' => 'required',
        'assigned_store' => Rule::requiredIf(in_array(request('checkout_to_type_contract'),['department','store'])),
        'assigned_department' => 'required_if:checkout_to_type_contract,department',
    ];
}
```